# Using Desktop.browse doesn't allow program to exit automatically

Tags: java, awt

If I make a simple program that browses to `google.com`, the program doesn't exit automatically when reaching the end of the `main` method. I would rather not call `System.exit(0)`, so I was wondering if there was a way to "close" the desktop thread so it can exit automagically.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://google.com"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you executing the code? From within an IDE or from the command line?  Which OS?

Comment: From an IntelliJ IDEA, I am using Ubuntu 15. Please tell my this is not platform dependent :(

Comment: On MacOSX (10.10.5) and Java 8, it works just fine from within Netbeans and from the command line (that is, the program shows the web page and terminates)

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong then, I am literally using that exact code snippet (inside a class of course). It opens in Firefox, I close the tab and it's still running. I don't have to close the browser do I?

Comment: I didn't have to. Have you tried to run the code from the command line? I added a shutdown hook just to check and that worked just fine

Comment: Doing it from the command line does allow it to exit normally. Why does this make a difference?

Comment: No idea, I've had issues with Netbeans and Windows executing external processes, which won't let the JVM terminate until the external process has terminated, go figure :P

Comment: But I'm not using Windows or Netbeans :P lol I guess the code works in production, but not in testing, kind of ironic I guess...

Comment: From my experince, once you're out of the IDE and running from Java itself, it seems to work as expected